# Espresso onData with check (assertion) on data object instead of View

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing

I have a `ListAdapter` for objects of type `Foo`. These objects have fields `int id` and `double quantity`.

In my Espresso tests, I would like to assert that the data entry with `id = 5` has `quantity = 10`.

(Assume that the methods `FooMatcher.withId(int)` and `FooMatcher.withQuantity(double)` exist and do what you would think they do.)

I could rely on how the adapter renders this visually, like so I believe:

```
onData(FooMatcher.withId(5))
  .onChildView(withId(R.id.quantityTextView))
  .check(matches(withText("10")));
```

(I haven't actually tested this but I guess it would work if the `double` value `10` is rendered as `"10"` inside a view with id `quantityTextView`.)

However, I don't want to rely on how the `double` value is rendered, which depends on localization and configuration options. It would be much more elegant if I could match the data directly, like so:

```
onData(FooMatcher.withId(5))
  .checkData(matches(FooMatcher.withQuantity(10)));
```

(This is pseudo-code; `.checkData()` doesn't exist. You can call `.check()` on the `DataInteraction` returned by `onData()` but it expects a `ViewAssertion` so if you use `matches(...)` it expects a `Matcher<? extends View>` whereas I want to use a `Matcher<Foo>`.)

Is there an elegant way to achieve something to this effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up solving this the following way for now.  If someone has a more elegant solution, please tell!

### Prerequisites

First of all, I'm using a `View` subclass called `ListItemView` for the views rendered by my `ListAdapter`. (I.e., the `getView()` implementation of my `ListAdapter` returns instances of `ListItemView`.)

I've added a field `public Foo item;` to my `ListItemView` class, and populate that field with a reference to the data object being rendered in the `getView()` implementation of my `ListAdapter`.

(This probably violates one or another principle of the Model-View-Controller pattern but I don't see any actual downsides to doing this in my codebase.)

### Basic idea

Now, since the view object has a reference to the data object, I can write a `ViewAssertion` that actually performs tests on the data object, like so:

```java
onData(FooMatcher.withId(5)).check(matches(new TypeSafeMatcher<>() {
    @Override
    protected boolean matchesSafely(View view) {
        if (view instanceof ListItemView v && v.item instanceof Foo foo) {
            return foo.quantity == 10;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void describeTo(Description description) {
    }
}));
```

(Note that this code uses Java 17 pattern variables, which is supported by the newest Android SDK.)

### Making it pretty

Of course, that's incredibly ugly, but we can make it pretty with a few helpers. Firstly, I already have the following subclass of `TypeSafeMatcher` to make it a little bit nicer to create ad-hoc Matchers using Lambda expressions:

```java
package org.example.myapp.tests.util;

import org.hamcrest.Description;
import org.hamcrest.TypeSafeMatcher;

import java.util.function.Predicate;

class PredicateMatcher<T> extends TypeSafeMatcher<T> {
    private final Predicate<T> predicate;
    private final String description;

    PredicateMatcher(Predicate<T> predicate, String description) {
        this.predicate = predicate;
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean matchesSafely(T item) {
        return predicate.test(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void describeTo(Description description) {
        description.appendText(this.description);
    }
}
```

In addition to that, I've now added a utility class called `Check` which allows for quick and easy creation of `ViewAssertion` instances :

```java
package org.example.myapp.tests.util;

import androidx.test.espresso.*;
import androidx.test.espresso.assertion.*;

import java.util.function.Predicate;

import org.example.myapp.model.Foo;

public class Check {
    // Generic checks on Foo objects using a Predicate<Foo>
    public static ViewAssertion foo(String description, Predicate<Foo> check) {
        return ViewAssertions.matches(new PredicateMatcher<>(description, view -> {
            if (view instanceof ListItemView v && v.item instanceof Foo foo) {
                return check.test(foo);
            } else {
                throw new RuntimeException("Type mismatch.");
            }
        }));
    }

    // Check that a Foo has a given quantity.
    public static ViewAssertion fooQuantity(double quantity) {
        return foo("quantity is " + quantity, f -> f.quantity == quantity);
    }
}
```

Now my test codes looks very pretty:

```java
onData(FooMatcher.withId(5)).check(Check.fooQuantity(10));

// Use generic check method for properties that don't have a direct check:
onData(FooMatcher.withId(6)).check(Check.foo(
    "rarelyCheckedProperty is someValue",
    f -> f.rarelyCheckedProperty == someValue
));
```

And everyone lived happily ever after.